# Subversion 1.7.5 and svn-ant 1.3

Tags: svn, compatibility

I have SVN version 1.7.1 in a Solaris version 10 server and Tortoise SVN 1.7.1 in the client. I would like to upgrade the server to SVN 1.7.5 however we have ant scripts in the system using svn-ant 1.3

Does anyone knows whether svn-ant 1.3 is compatible with the new Subversion 1.7.5 and if you do where to find documentation about this interaction or any details?... Thanks.

Comment: Switch to Git, and Maven. SVN and ANT are a pain, and not so efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your legacy ant scripts work with Subversion 1.7.x and working copies created with clients 1.7.x if you update your svnkit libraries. The latest SVNKit 1.7.8 supports 1.7.x working copy format and Subversion 1.7 servers. See [Subversion 1.7 Compatibility](http://svnkit.com/download.php)  for details

*Note that my answer is for svnkit use only. For the use of javahl, I will try to update this answer if possible.*

**Setup**

You need to update the svnkit related libraries with latest SVNKit release (1.7.8 or above). The shipped svnkit libraries in svnant 1.3.1 won't work with Subversion 1.7
Libaries required from svnant 1.3.1:

- svnant.jar
- svnClientAdapter.jar

Libraries needed from SVNKit 1.7.8:

- svnkit-1.7.8.jar
- svnkit-javahl16-1.7.8.jar
- antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
- sequence-library-1.0.2.jar
- sqljet-1.1.6.jar

**Ant Script**

```
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
      target: svn-test                      
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<target name="svn-test">
    <svnSetting svnkit="true" javahl="false" username="foo" password="bar" 
        id="svn.config" />
    <svn refid="svn.config">
        <info target="${basedir}" />
    </svn>
        <echo>${svn.info.lastRev}</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed worked for me (svnkit 1.7.9). The only one issue I've - svnSettings doesn't work for me. Must use username/password directly in svn

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information on [tigris](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1045&dsMessageId=2758110) i would say. You can checkout from a server with 1.7.X but you can't use a working copy which has been checked out by 1.7.X clients, cause the working copy format has changed in 1.7.X.

Comment: +1 since SvnAnt is built against SVNKit 1.3.x and that [SVNKit site](http://svnkit.com/download.php) states that: "Previous version of SVNKit (1.3.8) is **not compatible** with Subversion 1.7 working copy format and **compatible** with Subversion 1.7 servers."